# XML to VBA Excel

Tags: xml, vba, excel

Good afternoon guys,

I'm trying to get a table data from a xml file through this link, in order to automate a report:
http://channels9.us.dell.com/netagent/scripts/srvgate.dll?Action=10020&XMLType=A_OnlineOffline_Result

However all I've tried gives me errors.

I'll have to input a login and password and access this link to get the xml as below:

```
<information>
<reset>10/9/2014 8:24:07 AM</reset>
<date>10/9/2014 10:49:45 AM</date>
<header>
<statheader id="0">Agent</statheader>
<statheader id="6">Current online/offline time</statheader>
<statheader id="1">Login time (server local)</statheader>
<statheader id="5">Online status</statheader>
<statheader id="4">Times offline</statheader>
<statheader id="3">Total time offline</statheader>
<statheader id="2">Total time online</statheader>
</header>
<statistics>
<item id="41810">
<statistic id="0">A_G_Silva A_G_Silva</statistic>
<statistic id="6">01:20:43</statistic>
<statistic id="1">10/9/2014 9:29:02 AM</statistic>
<statistic id="5">Unavailable</statistic>
<statistic id="4">0</statistic>
<statistic id="3">00:00:00</statistic>
<statistic id="2">00:00:00</statistic>
</item>
<item id="40663">
<statistic id="0">Alan_Dominguez Alan_Dominguez</statistic>
<statistic id="6">02:21:00</statistic>
<statistic id="1">10/9/2014 8:28:45 AM</statistic>
<statistic id="5">Unavailable</statistic>
<statistic id="4">0</statistic>
<statistic id="3">00:00:00</statistic>
<statistic id="2">00:00:00</statistic>
</item>
</statistics>
</information>
```

Do you know how can I do this through VBA?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add two references to your VBA project:

1. Microsoft Internet Controls
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library

---

The HTML behind the fields has an `id = password` and `id = username` which makes it pretty easy to locate using getElementById

Here is a working example of filling in the fields and submitting the form:

```
Sub PushAddPhotoButton()
    Dim IEexp As InternetExplorer
    Set IEexp = New InternetExplorer
    IEexp.Visible = True
    IEexp.navigate "http://channels9.us.dell.com/netagent/scripts/srvgate.dll?Action=10020&XMLType=A_OnlineOffline_Result"

    'Wait for page to load
    Do While IEexp.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'Fill in user name and password
    IEexp.Document.getElementById("username").Value = "myUsername"
    IEexp.Document.getElementById("password").Value = "myPassword"

    'Submit form
    IEexp.Document.getElementById("submit").Click

    'Wait for page to load again
    Do While IEexp.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'Do what you need to do here to get XML
    'If you don't do anything then the IE browser will just flicker and close

    IEexp.Quit
    Set IEexp = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

Here is a screen shot with the script stopped right before the button click.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I'm getting an error: Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Automatic error - The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

Comment: Set userName = IEexp.Document.getElementById("username")

Comment: It was already, tried with Low and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Okay, I verified that it's not security too.  I commented out the wait line (Do While) and got the same error.  The page is loading to slow and the element can't be found.  You can test this by stepping through your code manually (F8).  Make sure the webpage fully loads before stepping past the username line.  If it works than this verifies that it's a timing issue.

Comment: hmm tried it also and same.. I've google it this error and it looks like it has a lot of different issues on that specific error. :/

Comment: IE11 also.. Windows 8.1, and you?

Comment: IE11 and Windows 7, hmmm.

Comment: As `INPUT` form elements, setting the *username* and *password* should be to the `.Value`, not the `.InnerText`. e.g. `IEexp.Document.getElementById("username").Value = "myUsername"`.

Comment: @Jeeped Good point, both work for me but that is the correct approach so I updated the post.

Comment: Tried in a colleague pc and works as well as yours, but in mine nope! haha no clue what can I do lol

Comment: Try changing to _Medium_: `Set IEexp = New InternetExplorerMedium`